# Why does evaluating an integral within a Plot expression take so long?

Tags: plotting, evaluation

I want to evaluate

```
Plot[Integrate[Sin[((1 + 1/2) x)] (1/(2 Sin[(x/2)]) - 1/x), {x, 0, t}], {t, 0, 5}]
```

but it takes ages to load on Corei3 computer with *Mathematica* 9.

I'm still a novice when it comes to using *Mathematica*. Is there a way to get this expression to be evaluated faster? (I'm not used to waiting more than a minute while computing, that's why it feels odd to me).

Comment: I can't answer the "Why" question but `fun[t_] = Integrate[Sin[((1 + 1/2) x)] (1/(2 Sin[(x/2)]) - 1/x), {x, 0, t}]; Plot[fun[t], {t, 0, 5}]` is fast while doing everything at once is very slow indeed.

Comment: Strongly related: [How to speed up the plot of NIntegrate?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23854/4330)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Oska nailed it in the comments before me*

The trick here is to evaluate the integral only once. In your code it is being evaluated once for every point. You can evaluate the following

```
Integrate[Sin[((1 + 1/2) x)] (1/(2 Sin[(x/2)]) - 1/x), {x, 0, t}]
```

The outcome of this is

```
ConditionalExpression[1/2 (t + 2 Sin[t] - 2 SinIntegral[(3 t)/2]), 
 t \[Element] Reals]
```

You know that `t` will always be a real number (at least in your plot), so you can just copy paste the first argument of this `ConditionalExpression` and make a function out of it.

```
func[t_] := 1/2 (t + 2 Sin[t] - 2 SinIntegral[(3 t)/2])
```

We can then do

```
Plot[func[t], {t, 0, 5}]
```

which gives

[image]

To define the function "automatically", you could use the code in Oska's answer. I slightly prefer the following

```
func[t_] := Evaluate@
  Integrate[Sin[((1 + 1/2) x)] (1/(2 Sin[(x/2)]) - 1/x), {x, 0, t}, 
   Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals]
```

Which gets rid of the `ConditionalExpression` and uses `SetDelayed` rather than `Set`. The code only works if `t` does not have value, so watch out.