# WorkingPrecision in NDSolve causes failure when solving a simple PDE

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, precision-and-accuracy, arbitrary-precision

I have fivefold multiple integral and I wanted a speed calculations. I came across on this [*Question*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23854/how-to-speed-up-the-plot-of-nintegrate) and had already begun the problems.

**Here is a toy example with simple double integral:**

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2*y^2;
NIntegrate[f[x, y], {y, -3, 3}, {x, -3, 3}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
(* 324.00000000000000000 *)

sol2 = NDSolve[{D[u[x, y], x, y] == f[x, y], u[-3, y] == 0, 
u[x, -3] == 0}, u, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]; 
u[x, y] /. sol2 /. x -> 3 /. y -> 3

(* 324. *)
```

Yes works,but I change `WorkingPrecision` in `NDSolve` they begin to happen strange things:

> With `WorkingPrecision -> 2`

[image]

> With `WorkingPrecision -> 5`

[image]

> With `WorkingPrecision -> 10`

[image]

I have MMA on Windows 8.1 `"10.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)"`

---

**EDITED: 07.06.2018**

On Mathematica `11.3`:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2*y^2;
sol2 = NDSolve[{D[u[x, y], x, y] == f[x, y], u[-3, y] == 0, 
u[x, -3] == 0}, u, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, WorkingPrecision -> 5];
u[x, y] /. sol2 /. x -> 3 /. y -> 3
```

or:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2*y^2;
sol2 = NDSolve[{D[u[x, y], x, y] == f[x, y], u[-3, y] == 0, 
u[x, -3] == 0}, u, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
PrecisionGoal -> 8, AccuracyGoal -> 8];
u[x, y] /. sol2[[1]] /. x -> 3 /. y -> 3
```

gives error: `` NDSolve::initf: The initialization of the method NDSolve`StateSpace failed. ``.

Issue still persist on MMA `11.3`.

With no options like:`WorkingPrecision`,`PrecisionGoal`, `AccuracyGoal` works fine.

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2*y^2;
sol2 = NDSolve[{D[u[x, y], x, y] == f[x, y], u[-3, y] == 0, 
u[x, -3] == 0}, u, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}];
u[x, y] /. sol2[[1]]/. x -> 3 /. y -> 3
(* 324.*)
```

Comment: I guess don't try to use non-`WorkingPrecision` when it's explicitly stated that `WorkingPrecision` is the only level of precision allowed?

Comment: `NDSolve` insists on using the `IDA` package for this particular PDE, and `IDA` evidently does not accept `WorkingPrecision` as an option, even `WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision`.

Comment: Incidentally, `DSolve` cannot solve the particular PDE either, even though the solution is obvious: `81 + 3 x^3 + 3 y^3 + (x^3 y^3)/9`

Comment: I'm afraid "`PrecisionGoal` works fine" isn't related to the issue here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118249/1871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very strange, `NDSolve` seems to insist on discretizing the PDE to a DAE system, but it should be able to discretize it to a set of ODEs rather than DAEs. The following is a self implementation of method of lines. I'll use [`pdetoode`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for discretization.

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2*y^2;
grid = Array[# &, 25, {-3, 3}];
(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this code piece,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoo = pdetoode[u[x, y], x, grid, 4];

ode = D[u[x, y], x, y] == f[x, y] // ptoo;
ic = u[-3, y] == 0;
odeic = ic // ptoo;
bc = u[x, -3] == 0;
odebc2 = With[{sf = 10}, ptoo@diffbc[x, sf]@bc];

sollst = NDSolveValue[{Rest@ode, odeic, odebc2}, u /@ grid, {x, -3, 3}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 16];

sol = rebuild[sollst, grid];
sol[3, 3]
(*323.9999999697654*)
Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As far as I can tell, the above code is just a self implementation of `WorkingPrecision -> 16, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 10}, "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 25, "MinPoints" -> 25, "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}`, but adding these options to `NDSolve` won't resolve the problem. Maybe it's a bug, maybe it's due to another [undocument feature of `"MethodOflines"`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/129183/1871). I suggest you to report it to WRI.

Comment: I'm raported to WRI.