# Table in NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, list-manipulation

I have an integral that I want to evaluate it once and store its values in a table so that I don't run the integration each time that I want to plot it. 
Its form is `int[x_,y_]:=NIntegrate[f[z],{z,x,y}]` with the functional form of `f[z]` being irrelevant for the time being and `x,y` being in the range of `[1,1000]` and specified each time that I plot it. How do I do a table that essentially is a function of `x,y` (and takes the values from the table rather than re-integrating everything each time)?

Comment: Instead of defining the function, define a table: `ints = Table[NIntegrate[f[x], {z, x, y}], {x, 1, 2}, {y, 3, 6}]`. Either that, or memoize: `int[x_, y_] := int[x, y] = NIntegrate[f[z],{z,x,y}]`, but I recommend the first.

Comment: Ok, if I go for the first method, how to I plot it afterwards from say `x=1` to `y=1000`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "plot it from `x = 1` to `y = 1000`", because those are two different variables.

Comment: Yeah my mistake I didn't explain it properly. By defining the table essentially I have a function `ints[a,b]` and I want to be able to do plots like `Plot[ints[1,r],{r,1,1000}]` and `Plot[ints[r,1],{r,1,1000}]`. Is something like that possible? Thank you

Comment: Use `Interpolation`: `data = Table[{{x, y}, NIntegrate[f[z], {z, x, y}]}, {x, 1, 1000, 
    999/99}, {y, 1, 1000, 999/99}];

ints = Interpolation[data];`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59891/interpolating-an-antiderivative

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23854.

Answer (score 1):

`NDSolve` will compute a numeric antiderivative.

Example:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[t_] := Re@Zeta[1/2 + Sqrt[t] I];

Plot[f[t], {t, 1, 1000}]
```

[image]

The antiderivative:

```
ListLinePlot@NDSolveValue[{y'[t] == f[t], y[1] == 0}, y, {t, 1, 1000}]
```

[image]

Here's the definite integral `int[x, y]`:

```
ClearAll[int];
With[{F = NDSolveValue[{y'[t] == f[t], y[1] == 0}, y, {t, 1, 1000}]},
  int[x_, y_] := Subtract @@ F[{y, x}]
  ];

Plot3D[int[x, y], {x, 1, 1000}, {y, 1, 1000}]
```

[image]

For greater accuracy, use

```
NDSolveValue[{y'[t] == f[t], y[1] == 0}, y, {t, 1, 1000}, InterpolatingOrder -> All]
```