# Can this type of function be plotted faster using NDSolve instead of NIntegrate?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

In this post [How to speed up the plot of NIntegrate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23854/how-to-speed-up-the-plot-of-nintegrate?newreg=9c3a3752c49c4d998719a0aabe33bf6f) it was suggested that we can speed up the plotting of `NIntegrate` by using `NDSolve` instead. Can a similar way be done to plot this type of function

```
f[x_] := NIntegrate[Exp[-x y z - y^(1/2) - z^(1/2)], {y, 0, ∞}, {z, 0, ∞}];

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}] // Timing
```

How can I apply `NDSolve` to this function?

Answer (score 6):

> How can I apply `NDSolve` to this function?

Do you want to apply `NDSolve` or do you want to plot the integral faster?

The plot can be produced ≈ 20 faster using appropriate option settings.
Here is an example:

```mathematica
Clear[f2];
f2[x_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[Exp[-x y z - y^(1/2) - z^(1/2)], {y, 0, Infinity}, {z, 0, Infinity}, PrecisionGoal -> 2, AccuracyGoal -> 3, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];
```

```mathematica
Plot[f2[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.694531 *)
```

[image]

Comment: To answer your question I just want to plot the integral faster because some functions I have are more complicated than this and they take much longer.

Comment: Ok. Do the options above help? For complicated integrals using less precision and accuracy might make `NIntegrate` "skip" certain singularities. If the integrals have more or less the same shape then "en bloc" numerical integration can be used; see 
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126041  .

Answer (score 4):

*Note: This is an extended comment.*

This integral can be expressed in terms of the [`MeijerG` special function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeijerG.html):

```
16/π*MeijerG[{{1},{}},{{1,1,3/2,3/2},{}},1/(16*x)]
```

Plotting using this expression takes about 6 seconds, compared to 12 seconds using OPs code. To obtain this expression, I first made a change of variables, replacing `y` by `u/z` where `u` is a new variable, and then evaluated the resulting integral

```
Integrate[Exp[-x*u-(u/z)^(1/2)-z^(1/2)]/z,{u,0,∞},{z,0,∞},
          Assumptions->{x>0}]
```

which takes about 10 seconds and gives the `MeijerG` result.

Having a symbolic result has advantages besides plotting, for example if OP wanted to know about $x \to \infty$ asymptotics, they could use

```
Series[16/π*MeijerG[{{1},{}},{{1,1,3/2,3/2},{}},1/(16*x)],{x,∞,1}]
(* (-EulerGamma+Log[16]+Log[x]+2 PolyGamma[0,1/2])/x+O[1/x]^(3/2) *)
```